# How to remove carriage return in vi

Tags: vi

I have a file that's failing due to a single carriage return at the end (0x0D). It was originally a carriage return/new line combination (0x0D, 0x0A). I've tried:

- deleting it in INSERT mode (deletes the last printing character and leaves the carriage return)
- `%s/\r//` (`E486: Pattern not found: \r`)
- `%s/^M//` (Ctrl+V, Ctrl+M to get `^M`) (`E486: Pattern not found: ^M`)
- `J` to join with the next line (appears to do nothing to the last line)

All of them leave the carriage return in place.

How can I get rid of this character from within `vi` (not `vim`)?

#### EDIT

Now it appears it's adding a new line character (0x0A) whenever I save the file. So, the 0x0D is gone, but I still have an invalid character at the end of my file.

I tried adding two blank lines to see if it would add 0x0A or 0x0D, 0x0A (I'm using PuTTY from Windows) and it added two 0x0A characters, for a total of three.

If you have three lines, shouldn't you only need two line separators?

- `%s/\n//` (no error, but doesn't remove the character)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally found an answer elsewhere:

`:set noendofline binary`

Removes the final new line when the file is saved.

Comment: man you saved my life... thank you so much...